# Mappings defined in vimrc file only work sometimes?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

In my .vimrc-file I have these commands:

```
" Add normal cursor-behavior on screen
noremap  <buffer> <silent> k gk
noremap  <buffer> <silent> j gj
noremap  <buffer> <silent> 0 g0
noremap  <buffer> <silent> $ g$
```

So when I press `j`, then it goes down one *visual* line on the screen. However... Sometimes when I load a document, then that doesn't always work. It's strange because sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

For instance, when I created a `temp.txt`-file on my desktop, copied in a long line and made a `:vsplit` (to make the screen more narrow)... Then it worked as it should.

But if I used `vim ftp://username@host//`, opened a file in a tab, did a `:vsplit`, then it *didn't* work! ... Here comes the strange part. I then close that file, with the ftp-connection still open. Then I repeat the *exact same procedure*, and then it works.

The thing that *always* fixes it, is to write `:so $MYVIMRC`. Regardless of where I am (FTP-server, locally, whereever), - then writing that, fixes it.

I tried to move the four lines to the bottom of my `.vimrc`-file, but with no luck. My best guess is that Vim loads some other `.vimrc`-file after my `$MYVIMRC`-file sometimes, which overwrites this command. So I checked, by writing `:version`, which gave this output:

```
system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
```

Are there a way, where I can ensure that Vim, in a way, always do a `:so $MYVIMRC` as the last thing, after it has loaded?

I have Vim-version 7.4, compiled by Homebrew and are working on a Mac.

Comment: Try removing `<buffer>` keyword, I think it doesn't make sense when defined in `.vimrc` in global scope (without `autocmd`. or smth like that).

Comment: ^that. Vimrc isn't read for each buffer that's loaded, and mappings with `<buffer>` are only set for that buffer, so this would only apply to the first buffer (and to any in which you manually run `:so $MYVIMRC`). @grodzik maybe post an answer.

Comment: yeah, `<buffer>` makes no sense outside of `autocmd`. But as another aside, please note that ftp transmission is not secure and your username and password are transmitted unencrypted. Consider `scp` or `sftp` instead if this matters in your working enviroment.

Comment: That seems to work! Yeah, @grodzik - please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `<buffer>` keyword. Adding it makes a mapping local to a buffer (`:h map-<buffer>`), and if used in global scope in`.vimrc` makes it valid for the first buffer only (or the one in which `.vimrc` was sourced).

Comment: What does `<buffer>` do, by the way?

Comment: Like I wrote, makes mapping local to a single buffer, see help `map-<buffer>`